# Flow with redux - passing union type gives error

Tags: javascript, redux, flowtype

I have this type:

```
export type Action<P> = {
  type: string,
  payload: P
}
```

I now need to pass a return type to `Dispatch`, which I want to be an `Action<number>` or an `Action<boolean>`

Why can I not do this?

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<Action<number | boolean>>) => {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      updateAlertModalHeight: updateAlertModalHeight,
      updateAlertModalIsOpen: updateAlertModalIsOpen,
      updateHasYesNo: updateAlertModalHasYesNo
    },
    dispatch
  )
}
```

It doesn't let me do `Action<number> | Action<boolean>` either.

The error is:

> Cannot call `bindActionCreators` because number [1] is incompatible
>   with boolean [2] in type argument `P` [3] of type argument `A` [4] of
>   property `updateAlertModalHeight` of type argument `C`. (References:
>   [1] [2] [3] [4])flow

Where am I going wrong?

Here is `updateAlertModalHeight` from the error message:

```
export const updateAlertModalHeight: ActionCreator<Action<number>, number> = (
  payload
) => ({
  type: UPDATE_ALERT_MODAL_HEIGHT,
  payload
})
```

and:

```
export const updateAlertModalIsOpen: ActionCreator<Action<boolean>, boolean> = (
  payload
) => ({
  type: UPDATE_ALERT_MODAL_IS_OPEN,
  payload
})
```

the two action creators have a different type and Flow is not allowing them to be used in the same `bindActionCreators` call. How do I get flow to allow it?

It all seems to work when I make everything this type:

```
export type ActionT = Action<boolean | string | number>

export const updateAlertModalIsOpen: ActionCreator<ActionT, boolean> = (
  payload
) => ({
  type: UPDATE_ALERT_MODAL_IS_OPEN,
  payload
})
```

and:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<ActionT>) => {
```

But that is less specific typing which sucks because it doesn't describe which type of action is being returned.

I would like to edit the redux type definitions to allow multiple Action types but it is difficult to understand what change to make.

Answer (score 1):

The generic type argument of `dispatch` is invariant, which means that it cannot be anything else than **exactly** what you specified — in particular, it cannot be specialized to `number` from `boolean|number`.  Intuitively,  the type information `number` is **more specific** than `boolean|number`.

The actual problem is the type of `bindActionCreators`, which enforces the same type argument as you give to `dispatch` to **both** `updateAlertModalHeight`, **and** `updateAlertModalIsOpen`. But these functions take different *types* of arguments! One takes a number, and one a Boolean, hence the type checker can't infer the types correctly. It works when you change the type argument of `updateAlertModalHeight` and `updateAlertModalIsOpen` to allow for being called with either type, i.e. saying "it's OK if you pass a number, I'll ignore it, and only act if you pass me a boolean." The type system sees it can pass **both** a `number` and `boolean` to the functions and therefore everything type checks.

The real solution here that does not rely on changing the argument types, would be to do two calls to  `bindActionCreators`, once with a `number`-`dispatch` and once with `boolean`-`dispatch`.

Comment: Thanks! It's strange but when I pass the wildcard to Dispatch, I get the same error about mixing types number and boolean. I think it uses type inference to see that the actions differ and disallows it. I tried to call bindActionCreators twice in the same mapDispatchToProps but the second call did not work.

Is there a way to make the more specific Action<boolean> and Action<number> inherit from and therefore BE ActionT?

Comment: Or typecast them as ActionT when using them?

Comment: Damn, I shouldn't just answer SO questions absent-mindedly at work. The wildcard won't work: it's the same reason why the `number | boolean` won't work. In the case of the wild card, the type gets specialised to one of the types first, and then doesn't fit the other anymore. So scratch that, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I think that conceptually, the way that `bindActionCreators` is written, you can't pass in a generic dispatch and expect to call functions with different argument types inside.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to make two calls to bindActionCreator? I can't find an example online. It doesn't seem to be common. I tried doing them both by not returning the bindActionCreator calls, and  just calling them instead, but it made the AlertModal component not show the alert messsage in the modal so something was wrong with the way I called it twice.

Answer (score 0):

To move forward I have gotten flow to be quiet by getting rid of my custom type `Action` and am importing Redux's type `Action` E.G. `import type { Action } from 'redux'`. The one Redux uses is

```
  declare export type Action<T> = {
    type: T
  }
```

I find it a bit weird because the `type` field is always a string in a redux action. E.G `'UPDATE_ALERT_MODAL_IS_OPEN'`. So it is pointless to specify string. I always type them with `Action<string>`

My action creator becomes:

```
export const updateAlertModalIsOpen: ActionCreator<Action<string>, boolean> = (
  payload
) => ({
  type: UPDATE_ALERT_MODAL_IS_OPEN,
  payload
})
```

mapDispatchToProps becomes:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<Action<string>>) => {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      updateAlertModalIsOpen,
      updateAlertModalHeight,
      updateHasYesNo: updateAlertModalHasYesNo
    },
    dispatch
  )
}
```